# How do I render a partial view within another view's partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

**Example**:

`_detail.html.erb` is in products views and I want to render this partial inside in my `_medicine.html.erb` partial that is in `pets` view.

**Error message**:

> missing template error in pets#new saying missing 'partial
>   products/detail'

`pets/_medicine.html.erb` has this code:

```
  <%= render 'products/detail' %>
```

Comment: Can you post some more code please

Comment: Add paths to both partials relative to your project root.

Comment: Try <%= render '/products/detail' %> (mind the slash)